# Handling a big eloquent result that must be posted to a service bus as a JSON message

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I am building a Laravel artisan command that must handle a very large result of an eloquent query. The result must be posted by HTTP to a service bus as a JSON based message.

The problem now is that the command runs out of memory when the result set is converted to a array first (after which it will be converted to JSON).

One solution would be to raise de default memory size of 128MB per PHP process. An other solution would be to handle the results in smaller chunks and write the JSON results to a temporary file. When finished read out the complete file again and post the JSON to the bus.

But I wonder if there are more solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using pagination or offset?

Comment: The result must be posted to the bus as one single post request.

Comment: Client could request more data from server with the next page url. Whole services that get lots of requests and give a big data limit their response and the ball is given to the client.

Comment: It is not a client request but a post action to a server (a service bus). The server must receive the JSON message in one big post.

Comment: Paginate and concatenate.